# Basic svn merge/switch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I'm cautiously playing with svn merge on a large codebase, and I'm not too familiar with this command. Is the following the right way to proceed:

- I had a trunk
- I did `svn cp trunk branch` and then did many modifications in the branch
- then I did a merge by first copying my branch and then merging the trunk (which had recent modifications) into it: `svn cp branch both; svn merge http://.../trunk both`
- I fixed the conflicts and tested the merged version

Now I want to replace the trunk with the merged version. Is `svn mv trunk oldtrunk; svn mv both trunk` the proper way to proceed ? I don't understand what 'switch' really does.

Comment: Hi! The command `switch` is useful when you want to point a working copy to a different svn url e.g. you as a user are working in the trunk and you want to switch to a branch without touching your workspaces, configuration, etc. There's a good explanation here http://ldc.usb.ve/docs/svn/svn.branchmerge.switchwc.html This is useless in your case, you don't want to change a working copy but a svn directory. I would not do what you are proposing, `svn mv trunk oldtrunk; svn mv both trunk`, it is just dirty and might have implications. I would make the effort to merge again to the trunk. Sorry!

Comment: OK for merging... Even though that's gonna be time consuming. But when I try: `svn merge https://..../branch/ trunk/` I get `svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 5625 through 6454 were previously merged from https://.../trunk to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case Missing ranges trunk:6373,6378,6397,6402`

Comment: Hi! Well I think that depends on the version of `svn` you are using. Myself, I'm on a very old one, `1.6`. In mine, indeed when you perform `merge` you have to indicate explicitly from which version to which version you want to do the `merge`. Probably in the 1st one to `both` you did not have to, since it was new... Use `svn merge --help`... If you have doubts, tell me.